# Installing PyTorch via Conda

Tags: anaconda, torch, pytorch

Objective: Create a conda environment with pytorch and torchvision. Anaconda Navigator 1.8.3, python 3.6, MacOS 10.13.4.

What I've tried:

- In Navigator, created a new environment. Tried to install pytorch and torchvision but could not because the UI search for packages does not find any packages available matching pytorch, torch, torchvision, or similar strings.
- `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`
- `conda update --all`

pytorch 0.3.1, torch 0.3.1, and torchvision 0.2.0 now appear as installed in the root environment. However, the root environment is no longer cloneable; the clone button is gray/disabled (it used be enabled/cloneable). I could use the root environment as a fallback but the main point of conda is to be able to create separate and disposable environments. What am I missing?

UPDATE -----------------

Running `conda install -c pytorch pytorch` yields:
`# All requested packages already installed.` But if I activate the `pytorch` environment and list the packages therein, there is no package containing the word "torch". If I then do `conda search pytorch` I get `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - pytorch`. If I activate the `base` environment and then do `conda list` then pytorch is in the package list for base. So how does one create a separate environment containing pytorch?

Comment: did you try to create and install package and the same time: `conda create -n Ptorch pytorch torchvision` ?

Comment: Yes, it fails: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:  - pytorch`

Comment: Can you first activate the `base` environment, then install the libraries `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch` and try using that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You seem to have installed PyTorch in your base environment, you therefore cannot use it from your other "pytorch" env.

Either:

- directly create a new environment (let's call it `pytorch_env`) with PyTorch: `conda create -n pytorch_env -c pytorch pytorch torchvision`
- switch to the pytorch environment you have already created with: `source activate pytorch_env` and then install PyTorch in it: `conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision`

Comment: "remove pytorch from your base environment" <-- not strictly necessary, distracts a bit from your main point

Comment: You're right, it's just that he seemed to want PyTorch only installed in a dedicated env and he had already installed it in his base env

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this and was reminded to RTFM (Read The F'ing Manual) documentation...

See [`Verify the installation with import torch not pytorch.`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62724426/timeline) which is from [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-verification)