# Installed pytorch through conda, but cannot import in Windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pytorch, conda

When I issue an Anaconda prompt `conda search pytorch`
then I get pytorch installed even issuing `conda list` command gives me:

```
pytorch                   1.5.1           py3.7_cuda102_cudnn7_0    pytorch
```

But when I start python on command prompt and then issue `import pytorch` i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch'`.

Even I tried to do the same after issuing

```
conda create -n pytorch_env -c pytorch pytorch torchvision
conda activate pytorch_env
conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision
```

as written in [Installing PyTorch via Conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951846/installing-pytorch-via-conda?rq=1) but of no use. BTW does it require a restart of the machine after installing Anaconda? Also, let me know how I can use PyTorch in Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo (the module to import is `torch`, not `pytorch`).

Comment: on `import torch` i got `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`

Comment: On the Anaconda first screen, a dropdown for Applications on, I selected **pytorch_env** and then try to install **Jupyter Notebook** got the message `Multiple Errors Encountered.` *Taking me to https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#unsatisfiable*

Comment: Please edit the question to show what happens when trying `import torch`. I will be happy to retract the close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify the installation with `import torch` not `pytorch`. Example code below, [source](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-verification).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

If above throws same issue in Jupyter Notebooks and if you already have GPU enabled, try restarting the Jupyter notebook server as sometimes it requires restarting, [user reported](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4827#issuecomment-370762721).

> when I tried to import this package from Jupyter notebook, I got following error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'. Then, I tried installing Jupyter notebook application from Anaconda navigator for my environment(torch).
> Restarted my Jupyter notebook and ran import torch and this time it worked

Otherwise, you need CPU only version of PyTorch.

`conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch`

Comment: I have restarted the machine and `from __future__ import print_function
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)`
I am getting this message `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`
Is it possible that path is not set?

Comment: Please install the CPU-only version as I described and let me know

Comment: This. Thank you. I don't have a GPU but I installed the CUDA version on my Win 10 machine anyway thinking it would be a superset and would be downward compatible and it did not work. Per your suggestion, installed the CPU only version and it works now.